# How to query a list<T> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, generics

```
List<T> objectList = GetList();

foreach (T setName in setNames)
{
 List<T> list = objectList.Where(x => x.QualificationID == setName).ToList();
 redisClient.SetAdd<string>("Qualification:" + setName, list.Select(x => x.ProductID).ToString());
}
```

In Line 3, T does not contain a definition for 'QualificationID' and no extension method 'QualificationID' accepting a first argument of Type T could be found.

Similarly in Line 4,
T does not contain a definition for 'ProductID' and no extension method 'ProductID' accepting a first argument of Type T could be found.

how can we filter the list of generic object using linq?

**EDIT :** It is found not possible to filter the property value in a generic method until we specify the classtype.
like extending method to,

method() where T : ClassType

as specified in the answers and comment.

Comment: Use a `where T : SomeType` generic type restraint in your method/class declaration.

Comment: Could you eloborate with an example?

Comment: I suspect `list.Select(x => x.ProductID).ToString()` will yield nothing usefull, as `.Select()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, who's .`ToString()` method returns the type name.

Comment: Post an [mcve]. We ar least need to see the signature of GetList, and a basic idea of how you specify T.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a base type `BaseType` that has the public members `QualificiationID` and `ProductID`, you can do the following:

```
void Foo<T>() where T : BaseType
{
    List<T> objectList = GetList();

    foreach (T setName in setNames)
    {
        List<T> list = objectList.Where(x => x.QualificationID == setName).ToList();
        redisClient.SetAdd<string>("Qualification:" + setName, list.Select(x => x.ProductID).ToString());
    }
}
```

This assumes that the generic type is specific to the method. If it's a class-level generic, simply move the `where T : BaseType` to the corresponding place in the class declaration instead.

---

As a secondary point, the `ToString()` part of your second `.Select` call probably isn't doing what you think it's doing. `ToString` will try to convert the object into a string, which by default will return the type name. That means that all you're getting out of it would be something along the lines of `` "System.Linq.IEnumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`1" ``. In order to actually get a string from the LINQ, you will have to feed it to a string constructor and change it up a bit:

```
redisClient.SetAdd<string>("Qualification:" + setName, String.Join("", list.Select(x => x.ProductID.ToString()));
```

Comment: in my case the T can be of any classType.

Comment: @KaarthickRaman Obviously it can't, since not every class type has the `QualificationID` or `ProductID` members.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your compiler does not know that objects of type T has properties QualificationId and ProductId. You somehow have to tell it to the compiler.

The most generic way to do this, is to add a constraint to T informing the compiler that T has those two properties. This is done in a [where clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bb384067.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
void MyFunc<T>(T obj) where T : ...
```

Instead of the dots, you can put a base class of which you know that it has those two properties. More generic is that you supply an interface. You promise, that whenever you use `MyFunct`, that the supplied obj is of a type T that implements the interface:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    public int QualificationId {get;}
    public int ProductId {get;}
}

public void MyFunct<T>(List<T> objectList) where T: IMyInterface
{
    // here you know that any T implements IMyInterface,
    // and thus you can get QualificationId and ProductId

     List<T> list = objectList
        .Where(listElement => listElement.QualificationID == setName).ToList();
    redisClient.SetAdd<string>("Qualification:" + setName, 
        list.Select(listElement => listElement.ProductID).ToString());
}
```

The interface method is preferable above the base class method, because it gives you the opportunity to put use any T as long as it implements the interface, even if it has a different base class

As a side remark: I'm not sure what you want to do with SetAdd, but the result of your Select is probably a sequence of ProductIds. The ToString() of this sequence will describe the sequence, not the elements in the sequence. I'm fairly sure that is not what you want